# Vim keep showing error message about color scheme for no reason

Tags: vim

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
line 19:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'MyColor'
```

Those lines of errors keep yelling about cannot find color scheme. But, nothing is wrong. The colorscheme is exists in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors` directory. I've tried to put it in `~/.vim/colors/`, but vim keep complaints about those errors.

The colorscheme loaded just fine. Doing `:source` to my `.vimrc` file loaded everything just fine. Everything is fine except those lines of errors keep showing up, when starting vim and when sourcing `.vimrc` file even though everything works. What is this? And how can I fix this?

**INFO:** I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: Why did you put this to `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/`? That location belongs to Vim; you might lose your customizations on upgrade / reinstall of Vim. Is the script name exactly `MyColor.vim` (including case)?

Comment: The filename is lowercase. And the command to activate it too is lowercase. `mycolor.vim` and `colorscheme mycolor`

Comment: But the output complains about `MyColor`. Seems like the `g:colors_name` variable inside the script is using inconsistent case. Try renaming either to be consistent, then try again.

Comment: Do you have `syntax on`in your `.vimrc`file?

Comment: Fixed. It's because `g:colors_name` is set to capitalize. Thanks

Comment: Ah, great! I've added an answer; please accept by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given output complains about `MyColor`, but apparently the script's name is `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/mycolor.vim`. Seems like the `g:colors_name` variable inside the script is using inconsistent case. This may work on Windows, but Linux filesystems (and Vim's lookups) are sensitive to case. Try renaming either to be consistent, then try again.